# Disambiguate the Seat tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

There are currently 11 questions tagged [seat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat), a tag which has no wiki.

Of these, 8 are about the things you sit on in a vehicle and 3 are about models from the Spanish manufacturer.

We do have model-specific tags [seat-leon](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat-leon) and [seat-ibiza](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat-ibiza) and all three model questions tagged [seat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat) are about the Ibiza.

Shouldn't we make it clear in the [seat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat) tag wiki that it is for the things you sit on, retag the three rogue questions with [seat-ibiza](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat-ibiza) and possibly create a new tag for the Seat marque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a [seat-cars](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat-cars) tag for the company, and added it to the ibiza and leon questions. I've also added a wiki to both that and the [seat](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seat) tag to clarify which is which...